# is there a better way to write return statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, return, prompt

I'm creating a sign up page using prompt(), i want to return from the page when a user cancels. i tried using return statement to achieve this but it gave an error _ **illegal return statement**. *I wrote the same code without a constructor or the idea of OOP and I really want to get same result using constructor or the idea of OOP if possible* here is my code

```
let getuserName = prompt("enter your user Name")

while (validateUserName(getuserName) == false) {
    getuserName = prompt("invalide user, user name most be less than 10")

}

if (getuserName == null) {
    return
}* //this is showing illegal return*

let getpassword = prompt("enetr your password")

while (validatePassword(getpassword) == false) {
    getpassword = prompt("password most be 10 0r more")

}

//confirm password

let getconfirmPassword = prompt("please confirm your password")

while (getconfirmPassword !== getpassword) {
    getconfirmPassword = prompt("invalid password, please enter a valid password")

}


class user {

    constructor(userName, firstName, lastName, email, accountValidated, password, confirmPassword) {
        this.userName = userName || "Anonymous";
        this.firstName = firstName || "Anonymous";
        this.lastName = lastName || "N/A";
        this.email = email || " "
        this.accountValidated = accountValidated || null;
        this.password = password || null;
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword || null;
    }
    getuserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    getfullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

    getemail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    getvalidation() {
        return this.accountValidated;
    }

    getpassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    getconfirmPassword() {
        return this.confirmPassword
    }

}

const user1 = new user(`${getuserName}`, "josephine", "nnalue", "josephinennalue@gmail.com", true, "josephine123")
const user2 = new user("Amara123", "Amarachi", "Simon", "amarachisimon@gmail.com", true, "amarachi123123")
const user3 = new user("chi123", "Chika", "Okoye", "chikaokoye@gmail.com", false, "chika123")
const user4 = new user("ble123", "Blessing", "Jimmy", "blessingjimmy@gmail.com", true, "blessing123")
const user5 = new user("seunbaby", "Seun", "Kareem", "seunkareem@gmail.com", false, "seun123")




console.log(user1.getuserName())

//validating user name

function validateUserName() {
    if (getuserName == null) {
        return true
    }

    if (getuserName.length > 10) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}


console.log(validateUserName())


//validating password

function validatePassword() {
    if (getpassword.length < 10) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

console.log(validatePassword())
```

Comment: Since you are not inside a function-scope you cannot use return there. Either wrap the logic into a function or rewrite the logic so that you invert the expression in the if-clause and wrap the rest of the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some adjustments to your code to make it work and also simplified some of it. I've tried to reuse your code and logic as much as possible.

```js
function showPrompt() {
  function validateUserName(userName) {
    return userName.length < 10;
  }

  function validatePassword(password) {
    return password.length > 10;
  }

  let getuserName = prompt("enter your user Name")

  while (!validateUserName(getuserName)) {
    getuserName = prompt("invalide user, user name most be less than 10")
  }

  let getpassword = prompt("enter your password")

  while (!validatePassword(getpassword)) {
    getpassword = prompt("password most be 10 or more")
  }

  let getconfirmPassword = prompt("please confirm your password")

  while (getconfirmPassword !== getpassword) {
    getconfirmPassword = prompt("invalid password, please enter a valid password")
  }

  return {
    username: getuserName,
    password: getpassword
  }
}

const inputs = showPrompt();

class user {

  constructor(userName, firstName, lastName, email, accountValidated, password, confirmPassword) {
    this.userName = userName || "Anonymous";
    this.firstName = firstName || "Anonymous";
    this.lastName = lastName || "N/A";
    this.email = email || " "
    this.accountValidated = accountValidated || null;
    this.password = password || null;
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword || null;
  }
  getuserName() {
    return this.userName;
  }

  getfullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  getemail() {
    return this.email;
  }

  getvalidation() {
    return this.accountValidated;
  }

  getpassword() {
    return this.password;
  }

  getconfirmPassword() {
    return this.confirmPassword
  }

}

const user1 = new user(`${inputs.username}`, "josephine", "nnalue", "josephinennalue@gmail.com", true, "josephine123")
const user2 = new user("Amara123", "Amarachi", "Simon", "amarachisimon@gmail.com", true, "amarachi123123")
const user3 = new user("chi123", "Chika", "Okoye", "chikaokoye@gmail.com", false, "chika123")
const user4 = new user("ble123", "Blessing", "Jimmy", "blessingjimmy@gmail.com", true, "blessing123")
const user5 = new user("seunbaby", "Seun", "Kareem", "seunkareem@gmail.com", false, "seun123")

console.log(user1)
```